# iOS, How to screen record from pc

Tags: ios, iphone, screen-recording, xcrun

I know that there is a screen recording feature in iOS11.

I also know that there is some system command tool for iOS simulator to screen record, which is

> xcrun simctl io booted recordVideo --type=mp4

I found a command that I can do it for real Android device, which is

> adb screenrecord /sdcard/1.mp4

What I want to do is recording screen for real iOS device in terminal.
Can I do this?

I use

- IPhone8 plus
- iOS11.1
- iMAC

Comment: You can do the same via Quick Time Player

Comment: @SucharuHasija Could you tell me how can I do it in terminal?